# Packing k vertex trees

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, spanning-tree

Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices.

What do we know about packing of $k$ vertex trees, Both integral and fractional packing are interesting.

$k=2$, it is just the number of edges, hence trivial

$k=3$, it is packing of paths of length $2$, which is NP-hard. It is probably hard for every fixed $k\geq 3$. Fractional version is solvable in polynomial time, (in fact for all constant $k$, since we can write out the entire linear program)

$k=n$, we obtain the maximum spanning tree packing problem.

What about when $k$ is very close to $n$, so we are packing almost spanning trees. Say when $k=n-1$?

Comment: The question is not quite clear. My understanding is the following. For a given parameter $k$ you want to call a set of edges $A$ feasible if $A$ induces a tree with $k-1$ edges. Now you want to find the maximum packing of such feasible sets.   Is this correct?

Comment: Regarding computing (in poly-time) a fractional packing of subtrees with $k-1$ edges, I think that you can use Ellipsoid on the dual.  I think the separation oracle would be, given an assignment of non-negative weights to the edges, to decide whether there is a subtree with $k-1$ edges of total weight less than 1.  I think that problem is solvable in P by a variant of Prim's MST algorithm.  Similarly, you could compute a $(1+\epsilon)$-approximate fractional packing using MWU algorithms with that oracle.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri yes, that is much more clear. Edited the problem.

Comment: @NealYoung Thank you. Indeed, $k$-minimum spanning tree problem for constant $k$ or when $k=n-c$ for some constant $c$ is both solvable in polynomial time. So only remaining question is the integral packing and when $k=n-c$.

Comment: I don't understand your comment exactly.  Regarding the first sentence in your comment, I think finding a minimum-weight subtree with k vertices is in P for any k, not just k = O(1) or n-O(1).  Regarding the second, are you saying that you are only interested in integral packing when k = n - O(1)?  (So you don't care about the complexity for other k?)

Comment: The first part, finding $k$-minimum spanning tree is NP-hard if $k$ is part of the input. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-minimum_spanning_tree . second part: yes.

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken about the problem being in P!  Thinking more carefully I see why the variant of Prim's I had in mind fails.